# how to trigger event click similar to $(' ').trigger('click') does at div by function in angular 5?

Tags: angular5

### child2.component.html

```
<div class="child2">child2</div>
```

### app.component.html

```
<app-child2></app-child2>  // child2.component
    <div class="app">app</div>
    <div (click)="open()">button</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
open(){
    $('.child2').trigger('click');
    $('.app').trigger('click');
  }
```

I want to trigger using :-

```
let element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.child2')as HTMLElement;
  element.click();

 let element2: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.app') as HTMLElement;
  element2.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - add on identifier on your div,

```
<div class="child2" #child2>child2</div>
```

2 - In your component get the HTMLElement using @ViewChild decorator

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class MyChildComponent {

    @ViewChild("child2") myChild2;

public externalClick(){
    this.myChild2.nativeElement.click();
}
```

3 - In your AppComponent

```
@ViewChild(MyChildComponent) myChildComp : MyChildComponent;

open(){
 this.myChildComp.externalClick();
}
```

Comment: Getting Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: In app.component.ts......@ViewChild("child2") myChild2;  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.myChild2.nativeElement.click(); 
  }   and In child.component.ts,   <div class="child" #child2>child</div>

Comment: and you added #child2  on your div ?

Comment: to make @ViewChild work it need a selector,  it can be a  hashTag or a Component/Directive type

Comment: ok sorry :)  just missed this part there also many other way to do this,  but you can also in your AppComponent select another component. @ViewChild(Child2Component) child2Comp : Child2Component. Then you can simply call a public method on this component

Comment: I need to trigger click of a div using 'child2 class'  located in other component from different component as a jquery does above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180380/discussion-between-ahmad-mnzr-and-xrobert35).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180381/discussion-between-ahmad-mnzr-and-xrobert35).